# Constructor with parameter and array input doesn't work c++

Tags: c++

I am facing a problem to parameterize a constructor with array user input.

**My question is:**

> Create a class named `Student` and make a constructor with parameter like `Student(int i, string n, double s)` there are three private variables named `int id, string name, double score` and use `int getID(),string getName(),double getScore()` to taking input and use `void print()` for output. You need to define all the member functions including constructors.Then define 3 students in the main function. Get the values of the objects and output the details.

My code is given below:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
private :
    int id;
    string name;
    double score;

public:
    Student();
    Student (int i, string n, double  s)
    {
        id = i;
        name = n;
        score = s;
    }
    int getID()
    {
        cin >> id;
        return id;
    }
    string getName()
    {
        getline(cin,name);
        return name;
    }
    double getScore()
    {
        cin >> score;
        return score;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << id << " " << name << " " << score << " " << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Student stuArr[10];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "Student " << i + 1 << endl;

        cout << "Enter ID: " << endl;
        stuArr[i].getID();

        cout << "Enter name: " << endl;
        stuArr[i].getName();

        cout << "Enter marks: " << endl;
        stuArr[i].getScore();
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        stuArr[i].print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But my code doesn't work. It doesn't show any output. It builds, but doesn't give any output.

Comment: You sure it's building?  `undefined reference to Student::Student()`

Comment: I use codeblocks and  It shows the errors in the build log that you say here but not showing any error on the main editor.I can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the code is not even compilable, you should get an error: `undefined reference to Student::Student()`. Your constructor is missing body. Change `Student();` to `Student() {}`.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. If the answer solves the question please consider upvoting/accepting it.

Answer (score -2):

try to give values in the class itself, I mean while declaring the name,...etc variables.
and see if that gives you any output else, if it works then try to create objects manually without looping if it works then most probably your looping thing has some issue.

BTW, I am a python and dart student, I learnt C++ in my first year of graduation.(Not so good as I am with python and dart)!

Comment: Please consider commenting, this is more suitable for a comment than an answer.

Comment: yes, but I didn't had nor yet have enough rep to comment, So, I did this way, I am sorry btw!

Comment: Yes I see your intentions were only of helping, but stackoverflow has specific procedures to make the system more beneficial for everyone. It's ok, we all learn by making mistakes :)

Comment: Yes, And thanks for the help, I will won't repeat this again! ^^